# PDO mysql and PHP: Undefined index and Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Anyone please help me fix my php code here.
Im working with php and PDO and I have been switching codes around but nothing works. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code for my index page:

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';

$supportQuery = $conn -> query("
SELECT id, title, content
FROM table");

while ($row=$supportQuery ->fetchObjecy()) {
$support[]=$row;
}
?>

<?php if(!empty($support)): ?>
<?php foreach($support as $supp): ?>
<a href="page.php?id=<?php echo $supp->id; ?>&title=<?php echo $supp->title; ?>">
<?php echo $supp->title; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
No items found.
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code works the way I like it to work but when I run code and click the link, that is where I am getting errors.

Here is my php code for page.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';

$articleQuery = $conn -> prepare("
SELECT id, title, content
FROM table WHERE id='$id' and title='$title'");

while ($row=$articleQuery ->fetchObject()) {
$support[]=$row;
}
$articleQuery->execute();
?>

<?php if(!$_SESSION($support)): ?>
<?php echo $support->id; ?>
<?php echo $support->title; ?><br/>
<?php echo $support->content; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Are you inventing titles? Sorry but this page   doesnt exist nowhere.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need your help please. I am getting the following error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: title and id in /page.php
Notice: Undefined variable: support in /page.php
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /page.php
```

♡nbgmalimit

Comment: You say you are getting errors, what are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id and title in /page.php and Notice: Undefinwd variable: support in /page.php and Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /page.php

Comment: `$support[]=row;` => You missed a $ at `$row`.

Comment: And what is `$_SESSION($support)`? `$_SESSION` is an array, not a function. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php .

Comment: sorry about that $ in row im manually typing this through my phone. I cant go online thru my PC though.

Comment: And seriously, I don't know how $_SESSION works. That is why I decided to ask it here. If $_SESSION cant be used. What function should I use then?

Comment: Please edit your post with the **actual** code then. We don't want to look after typos that are not in the original code.

Comment: I have already updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to start...

1) In the 2nd code block, you need to execute the statement BEFORE trying to fetch the results.

2) You should be binding the values $id and $title prior to executing to avoid sql injection.

Look at the examples in the manual to see how to do both of these... 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

3) You're fetching the row as an object and adding the resulting object as a value in the $support ARRAY.

4) Assuming the id and title are unique, you do not need to loop it and add it to an array, as you should only get 1 row returned. Just use fetch. Using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC for the fetch style will return an array. Using PDO::FETCH_OBJ for the fetch style will return an object.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Try something like this...

```
$row = null;        
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, title, content FROM table WHERE id = :id and title = :title");
$stmt->bindParam( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->bindParam( ":title", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} else {
    // handle error
}
?>

<?php if(!empty($row)): ?>
<?php echo $row->id; ?>
<?php echo $row->title; ?><br/>
<?php echo $row->content; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Are you inventing titles? Sorry but this page   doesnt exist nowhere.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yet I am still getting error    Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in page.php on line 6.

Comment: Great. I managed to modify and get rid of the errors. Now when I tried executing the command; it is giving me a blank page as a result. Assuming that anyone can give me suggestions; I will try modifying to code.

Comment: It is finally working only if I add a specific value to $id and $title on the top. What I want to happen though is to return the value based on session. How is that possible?

Comment: Where are you wanting to get the values from for $id and $title? From query string perhaps? Also, you don't need to do a query with the title in it if the id column is unique. I would not recommend trying to assign and then get it from a session as you mentioned before that you do not understand sessions...

Comment: I would like to get the value of the $id and $title from the index page. I want the query to return the result of the id and title I set on index page when I clicked the link. I am thinking of adding code such as $id =$_SESSION['id'] but I dont know the syntax and create a query for it. The values are unique but it should be dynamic as well.